# Round prices to nearest $xx.99

Tags: php, rounding

**I want to round (up or down) prices to nearest $xx.99**

**For example:**

```
$17.99 -> Stay as is

$22.03 -> $21.99

$33.85 -> $33.99

$45 -> $44.99
```

Comment: How about just `round($price)-0.01`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add 0.01, round, minus 0.01

```
$input = 17.99; // example input
$add = $input + 0.01;
$round = round($add);
$output = $round - 0.01;
```

Or all-in-one:

```
return round($input + 0.01) - 0.01;
```