# Rounding up the prices to remove unwanted decimals - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, rounding

I'm trying to round up the prices to remove the unwanted decimals in the sum of all the prices.Below is the screenshot for example,[image]

So I need to adjust the prices to remove `.2` decimal from the total.I tried  below solution, but its only working for one set of prices not for other.

```
 <?php

$values = [436.4,207.3,87.3,218.2,196.4,54.6];


$final_array = $val_array = []; $sum =  0;

foreach($values as $v){

    $sum += roundValue($v, 5);
    $val_array[] = roundValue($v, 5);
}


function roundValue($number, $denominator = 1)
    {
        $x = $number * $denominator;
        $x = floor($x);
        $x = $x / $denominator;
        return $x;
    }


$final_array[] = ['sum' => $sum, 'rates' => $val_array];

var_dump($final_array);

?>
```

Please check this running example for first set of prices: [first](https://eval.in/1044959)

Please check this running example for second set of prices: [Second](https://eval.in/1044970)

and even tried with all these solutions below, nothing works for me:

```
round($number + 0.01) - 0.01;
round($number + 0.05) - 0.05;
floor($number*100)/100;
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: With your second solution, why do you add 0.01 and then remove it? Surely [round()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) is what you want

Comment: If i have any prices like this `17.99`, I thought this can solve by using this formulae `round($number + 0.01) - 0.01;` , But now I realised this will not help with other prices. just tried this solution `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129514/round-prices-to-nearest-xx-99`

Comment: @IsThisJavascript : I tried with `round()` as well, did not work properly.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for or am I missing something? https://3v4l.org/IUVdR

Comment: You're rounding up the sum but i need the values to be rounded up to get the right sum.

Comment: You want the values to be rounded and then added together basically? Like this maybe? https://3v4l.org/aARXT

Comment: But if you see the sum for the first set of prices `[sum] => 1199` , this should be `1200`

Comment: I'm completely lost, sorry. Best of luck to you and others who try to help.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript : Okay, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is juggling types.

Notice, that `number_format` returns string. 
You are adding that string to integer (or float later), so php is implicitly casting that string to int/float.

What you want to do (probably) is to make your computations on floats/integers and at the end, when you'd like to display it - use `number_format`.

I would advise to do some reading on types.
[This](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php) will be a good start.

Comment: if you still has problems - please ask, I will happily try to help

Comment: Yes, I'm unable to solve this problem, I'm storing these prices in database as `double(8,2)` . I need to get these prices  to be rounded up to get the desired sum to use in excel.

Comment: Can you share your current code and describe what exactly is not working?

Comment: Yeah, The code is there in my question already, that's the same code I'm using now.

Comment: so is the problem only that those numbers are not in the form 11.22 (2 digits after decimal) inside of the Excel document?

Comment: Not exactly,I need to check the sum which  can't be round up to `1` after decimals then I need to adjust the prices in such way for the desired Sum.Example if the `sum = 1200.2,1200.35,1200.4`,then I need to adjust the prices to get the total as `1200.00`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177551/discussion-between-06011991-and-matiit).